# Planar convex region maximizing the difference in 'orientation' between its smallest containing rectangle and largest contained rectangle

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, convex-geometry, computational-geometry

We say a rectangle has orientation $\theta$ if the vector from its center to the middle of its shortest side (parallel to the longest side) has some angle $\theta$ with X axis.

Consider a planar convex region $C$ fixed in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let us draw $R_{1}$, the smallest rectangle containing $C$ and call the orientation of $R_{1}$, $\theta_1$. Let us also draw the rectangle $R_{2}$, the largest rectangle contained within $C$ and let its orientation be $\theta_2$.

[image: Example illustration]

**Question:** Which planar convex region $R$ maximizes $|\theta_1-\theta_2|$ ?

Note 1: If either rectangle is a square, the $\theta$ values won't be unique and we take the smallest value of $|\theta_1-\theta_2|$ as the orientation difference.

Note 2: The same question can be asked with area replaced with perimeter.

Related:
[bounds on largest internal rectangle area](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/147278/largest-inscribed-rectangle-inside-a-convex-polygon) and
[considering a simple case: right triangles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2124331/find-the-maximum-area-of-a-rectangle-placed-in-a-right-angle-triangle)

Comment: I'm really struggling to parse the question. "the orientation of a rectangle to be along its length" - what is this supposed to mean?

Comment: With serious inputs from Vallev (thanks!), the question has been edited. Hope it is clearer now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the convex hull of the union of a unit circle centered at the origin and an axis-aligned rectangle centered at the origin with dimensions of $2\times \sqrt{2}$. Now trim this shape slightly by cutting away the left and right edges by a width of $\epsilon$. This shape has a horizontal maximal inscribed rectangle and a vertical minimal containing rectangle.

[image: unrivaled artistic skill]

Comment: Thanks for this very simple and nice construction. It appears to solve both area and perimeter cases of the question.